# NSFetchedResultsController sorts in wrong order

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am working on a project based on the CoreData example from Xcode. I have a entity-class named `Entity` with a `updated` key which stores the timestamp that the entity was updated, and the NSFetchResultsController is set to sort with it in descending order:

> ```
> NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
> [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext]];
> [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
> [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"updated" ascending:NO]]];
>
> NSFetchedResultsController *frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
> ```

This works fine on the initial load, but when I insert a NSManagedObject that should be inserted in between the other objects, it gets inserted at the top. When I relaunch the app, it gets inserted at the right position.

e.g: initially the table would look like:

```
updated: 300
updated: 200
updated: 100
```

and when I insert a ManagedObject: `updated: 250`, I expect the table to look like:

```
updated: 300
updated: 250 <-- inserted here
updated: 200
updated: 100
```

but this is what I get:

```
updated: 250 <-- inserted at the top
updated: 300
updated: 200
updated: 100
```

Is this how NSFetchResultsController works, or is there any way to re-sort all NSManagedObjects on every insert? Thanks :)

Comment: When you insert a new object, how do you fetch?

Comment: delegate methods `-(void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller` ... gets called when the NSManagedObjectContext gets saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**My own answer**

NSManagedObject has it's method `isUpdated`, so having the entity with a key name `updated` was invalid.

> Methods you Must Not Override
>
> NSManagedObject itself customizes many features of NSObject so that
>   managed objects can be properly integrated into the Core Data
>   infrastructure. Core Data relies on NSManagedObject’s implementation
>   of the following methods, which you therefore absolutely must not
>   override: primitiveValueForKey:, setPrimitiveValue:forKey:, isEqual:,
>   hash, superclass, class, self, isProxy, isKindOfClass:,
>   isMemberOfClass:, conformsToProtocol:, respondsToSelector:,
>   managedObjectContext, entity, objectID, isInserted, **isUpdated**,
>   isDeleted, ...

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html

Comment: Thanks alot! been trying to figure out this problem for months now!

Answer (score 1):

In default, a new object would always be inserted to the top. You should keep an index of every objects if you would like to customize the sort. Then you can sort your objects in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can also , use an NSArray to sort in your delegate method

```
-(void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
  NSArrary *resultsArray = [controller allObjects];
  // sort 
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"updated" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [reultsArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
  // reload table using this array
}
```

Comment: thanks. can't I make NSSearchResultsController automatically sort results on every insert?